# Filter based on user provided values with ajax and django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to develop filter system. The filter system provides 3 options such as property type, number of rooms, and maximum price. Based on selected value among those options the user will get their search result. For example if user has selected property type of Appartment and number of rooms as 4 and maximum price of 12000 then the user will get those rent whose property type is appartment with 4 rooms of 12000 mark. I developed the frontend part with React.js and could fetch user selected data successfully. I have also passed data to ajax but I have no idea what should i do on server side (Django Views).Could anyone please enlighten me? Am i on the right track?

**My ajax code:**

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/filter/space/',
        data:{property:propertySelectedValue,room:roomSelectedValue,price:maxPrice},
        success:function(data){

        },
         error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
          },
      });
    },
```

**Views.py**

```
class FilterSpace(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        property = request.GET.get('property',None)
        room = request.GET.get('room', None)
        price = request.GET.get('price', None)
        rental = Rental.objects.all()
        if room:
            rental = rental.filter(room=room)
            print(rental)
        if price:
            rental = rental.filter(price__lte=price)
        if property:
            rental = rental.filter(property=property)
        rental_json = serializers.serialize('json',rental)
        return HttpResponse(rental_json),content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: `GET` is url request. And `require login` before process query ? But you need set header before sending data on server side.

Comment: Do you mean to say the use of      request.setRequestHeader()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume a Django model like this:

```
class Apartment(models.Model):
    rooms = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField() # Can use Decimal,
                                  # but who quotes real estate prices with decimals?
```

To accept filters as GET request params called `rooms` and `price`, we can a view like below:

```
from django.views.generic import View

class ApartmentSearch(View):
     def get(self, request):
          rooms = request.GET.get('rooms', None)
          price = request.GET.get('price', None)

          # The base query takes all apartments
          apartments = Apartment.objects.all()

          # If a filter param is passed, we use it to filter
          if rooms:
              apartments = apartments.filter(rooms=rooms)
          if price:
              apartments = apartments.filter(price__lte=price)

          # Here you need to convert to JSON
          apartments_json = <convert to JSON>

          return HttpResponse(apartments_json)
```

To send the parameters from jQuery I'd do:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/apartment/search",
  type: "get", // HTTP GET
  data: {property: ..., rooms: ..., price: ...}, // The filter object
  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried to print the value of property using print (request.GET.get('property')) which returned None on the console.

Comment: Basically form a JS object `{"property": ..., "rooms": ..., ...}` and give that to jQuery to send to Django

Comment: Updated the answer with jQuery snippet to pass that filer object

Comment: I tried this and wanted to show all the rent with the user provided value but i keep getting error saying TypeError: [<Rental: milan>] is not JSON serializable.I have updated my question with views.py and also ajax code.

Comment: rental_json =  serializers.serialize('json',rental) will solve your problem but i am confused with the difference of django serializers and json.dumps().They both are used for converting python objects to json , xml etc form.

Comment: How can i show all the rents that contains user provided values in my template?